# Can I use "Richardson Extrapolation" method to solve this following problem? is there any other method that I can use?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

[image]

I solved the population of 1955 using interpolation method .

**I just want to know which method can I use to solve the population of 1981? Can i use "Richardson Extrapolation"  to solve this problem? or any other method ?**

Comment: I'd object to the use of "science" in this context. The given data is too sparse. While interpolation will give you a reasonable value close to 3.0 for any method, extrapolation requires a valid model. You could fit a linear function or compute parameters for a quadratic polynomial, a hyperbolic function or an exponential function. The extrapolated values will be wildly different. /// Richardson extrapolation is for numerical methods where the value for stepsize $h\to 0$ is extrapolated. It does not apply here.